# All real values of $m$ for which $x^2-(m-3)x+m>0\forall x\in \left[1,2\right]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> All real values of $m$ for which $x^2-(m-3)x+m>0\forall  x\in \left[1,2\right]$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as $$x^2-(m-3)x+\left(\frac{m-3}{2}\right)^2+m-\left(\frac{m-3}{2}\right)^2>0$$

So $$\left[x-\left(\frac{m-3}{2}\right)\right]^2-\left[\frac{\sqrt{m^2-10m+9}}{2}\right]^2>0$$

So $$\left[x-\left(\frac{(m-3)+\sqrt{m^2-10m+9}}{2}\right)\right]\cdot \left[x-\left(\frac{m-3-\sqrt{m^2-10m+9}}{2}\right)\right]>0 $$

Now How can i solve after that , Help required, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)=x^2-(m-3)x+m$ and draw its graph.

[image]

Let $f(x)=x^2-(m-3)x+m$. $\forall x \in [1;2]$
$$f(x)>0 $$
Then

1) $D<0$

or

2) $ D\ge 0, f(1)>0, f(2)>0, f\left(\frac{m-3}{2}\right)\notin [1;2]$

Comment: I'm sorry, but to me your graph looks like it's is pretty hard to interpret unless one already knows what's going on. Perhaps you'd like to at least label/describe the regions $e,d,f$ are? Also the condition $f(-(m-3)/2) \notin [1,2]$ makes no sense to me. Perhaps you meant $f((m-3)/2) >0$?

Comment: @stochasticboy321. No, $f((m-3)/2)>0$ this is $D<0$ (case 1). If $D\ge 0$ then case 2.

Comment: All parabolas should pass through point $(1,4)$.

Comment: Okay, so then you mean $(m-3)/2 \notin [1,2]?$ Why are you considering the function's value at the minima at all in the case where you know that the parabola dips below the X-axis?

Comment: @stochasticboy321: the main thing $f(x)>0$ for $x \in [1;2]$

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what you've written says (according to the notation I know and some filling in of logic), that if the discriminant is positive, $f(1), f(2) $ should be positive, and $f((m-3)/2)$  should not be between $1$ and $2$. This is not equivalent to the statement $f(x) >0$ for $x \in [1,2]$.

Comment: Why this is not equivalent?

Comment: According to this, $f(m-3/2) = 0.5$ is not okay, while it clearly should be. Further, all this is a little moot. You need to define symbols you use (such as $D$) up front, and provide logic for why your statements are true! What does someone who doesn't know how to solve this problem learn from your answer? I may just be daft, but I'm certain I would have been super confused if I didn't already know how you were solving this.

Comment: If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ then $D=b^2-4ac$. 

I wrote the idea of the solution. I can easily carry through.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry but I don't agree with your curves @Roman83.

Here is how some of them look:
[image]

for values of parameter $m=0,1,\cdots 10$. If $m=0$ we get the parabola passing through the origin ; if $m=10$ we get the parabola which passes through point $(0,10)$, with increasing order between all of them.

Let us show how it gives us a **graphical evidence** (I don't say complete proof) of the solution.

Set apart the fact that all thesee parabolas pass through a common point $(1,4)$ (a fact that is easy to establish) what do we see on this graphics ? That the case $m=10$ is a limit case ; if m>10, we will have values of $x \in [0,2]$ such that expression $x^2-(m-3)x+m$ is negative.

The condition is then visibly fulfilled iff $m \leq 10$.

It remains to **prove it** (by algebraic means)...

Answer (score 1):

The following tries to build a solution from basic principles with a slightly pedagogical bent, and will perhaps appear clunky and too slow if you know a bit of calculus. I can only appeal to the precalculus tag, and hope that this is some help.

---

Define $f(x):= x^2 - (m-3)x + m$.

Let's first see what the question wants - it's essentially saying "I want to keep this parabola above the $x$ axis in this region, what values of $m$ let me do that?". Consequently, I should study the smallest value $f$ attains over $[1,2]$, and find the $m$s such that this is positive. Now, recall that a parabola $ ax^2 + bx + c, a>0$ attains it's minimum at $-b/2a$, which, in this case, is the point $x^* = \frac{m-3}{2}$. Let's consider the cases that can happen -

1. $x^* \in [1,2]$, which happens iff $5 \le m \le 7$ - Since we're going to be encountering  the minimum of $f$ in this interval, so we should make sure that it's positive, i.e., $f(x^*) > 0$. A bit of substitution will lead to the condition $4m > (m-3)^2$, which requires that $m \in (1, 9)$. Since we're only looking at $m$ between $5$ and $7$, this leads to the  condition $m \in [5, 7]$.
2. $x^* < 1 \iff m<5$. Since the minima is to the left of the interval we're interested in, the parabola will be increasing over it, and we simply need that $f(1) = 1 + 3 - m + m >0$ which is always true. Thus, $m \in (-\infty , 5)$ works for us.
3. $x^* >2 \iff m>7$. Now the reverse will happen - the parabola is falling over $[1,2]$, and we need $f(2)>0$ so that we stay above the $X$-axis. This requires $m<10$, and thus $m\in (7,10)$ also work.

Finally, we answer the question by listing all the $m$ where $f>0$. This is merely the union of the three regions determined above $ [5,7] \cup (-\infty,5)\cup (7,10) = (-\infty, 10)$.